# Set Text of ListItem from CodeBehind with Resources

Tags: c#, asp.net, resources

I generate my ListItems dynamically from CodeBehind and want as Text a Resource Property. I use the following code:

```
ddl_pdfalignment.Items.Add(new ListItem("<%$Resources:space.language, cb_portrait_addtable %>", "portrait"));
```

But my output is: *<%$Resources:space.language, cb_portrait_addtable %>* and not:

> PDF Orientationmode: portrait

which is saved in the Resource file.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
YourItem.Text = GetGlobalResourceObject("your_resource_file_name", "key_in_resource").ToString();
```

Try to use it